# Micro app router map->via with collections?

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

I'm setting up a Phalcon app using the Micro class.  I'm setting up my router to use the Collection class so that I can use a controller to split up the functionality and keep it fairly contained.

Now, what I'd like to do is have a route that handles both GET and POST.  With the normal micro app setup it looks pretty easy with `$app->add(…)->via(['GET', 'POST']);`.  However, the collections class offers a `map` method but nothing like a `via`.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do?  Code in the router looks simply like:

```
<?php
    use Phalcon\Mvc\Micro\Collection;

    $login = new Collection();
    $login->setHandler('Service\Controllers\LoginController', true);
    $login->setPrefix('/login');
    $login->post('/basic', 'usernameAction');
    $login->map('/social/{oauthProvider}', 'socialAction')->via(['GET', 'POST']);

    $app->mount($login);
```

(NB: this is just an included file, so auto-loading, defining `$app` and so on if fine, just in another file.  It also includes the map/via combination that doesn't work just to highlight what I'm trying to do.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that up to 3.2 of Phalcon (which I'm using) it's can't be done as I detailed above.  A `mapVia` method has been added to 3.3.x.

See further details from the [Phalcon forums where I also asked this question](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/17393/micro-app-router-mapvia-with-collection).